# Canonical way of updating/replacing a map value in `boost::hana::map`

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, c++14, boost-hana

What is the canonical way of updating a value *(given a key and a new value)* inside a [`boost::hana::map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1map.html)?

I tried using [`boost::hana::replace_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Functor.html#ga1d21b4bccd16367d164fbe0d9ef52150) but it does not work on `map` as it is not a `Functor` - I can get it to work by converting the `map` to a `tuple` and then back to a `map`, but it sounds inefficient.

The alternative I'm currently using is calling [`map::erase_key`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1map.html#af856f7bf77f69cdf1b8fd4e566eaef9b) followed by [`map::insert`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1map.html#af856f7bf77f69cdf1b8fd4e566eaef9b).

Is there any `replace` or `update` function designed for this purpose that I might be missing? Or is this the "canonical" way of updating a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is currently a canonical way to do this. If there are valid use cases for this, perhaps we could get a function in there to support it. The problem with `hana::erase_key` is that you will be creating a new map and then again with `hana::insert`. For the time being, using `hana::unpack` and then creating a new map is probably your best bet.

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename NewPair>
struct replace_helper_t
{
  NewPair const& new_pair;

  template <typename Pair>
  constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Pair&& p) const
  {
    return hana::if_(
      hana::equal(hana::first(new_pair), hana::first(p)),
      new_pair,
      std::forward<Pair>(p)
    );
  }
};

struct replace_t
{
  template <typename Map, typename NewPair>
  constexpr auto operator()(Map&& m, NewPair&& new_pair) const
  {
    return hana::unpack(std::forward<Map>(m),
      hana::on(
        hana::make_map,
        replace_helper_t<NewPair>{std::forward<NewPair>(new_pair)}
      )
    );
  }
};

constexpr replace_t replace{};

int main()
{
  auto my_map = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<7>, 7),
    hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<13>, 13),
    hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<23>, 23)
  );

  auto new_map = replace(my_map, hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<13>, 14.0f));

  BOOST_HANA_RUNTIME_ASSERT(new_map ==
    hana::make_map(
      hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<7>, 7),
      hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<13>, 14.0f),
      hana::make_pair(hana::int_c<23>, 23)
    )
  );
}
```

On another note, perhaps `hana::map` should be a `Functor`.

Comment: I believe you need your `hana::hash(hana::first(new_pair)) == hana::hash(hana::first(p))` test to be `hana::equal(hana::first(new_pair), hana::first(p))`. Otherwise, if you replace the value associated to a key whose hash collides with any other key in the map, you'll replace the value for all the keys that share the same hash even if the keys are different. Basically you'll replace the value for all keys in the same bucket. And a nitpick, but using `hana::equal` might be better than `==` for generic code because it'll work with e.g. `std::integral_constant`.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I fixed my example and also changed the type of the value to demonstrate that it isn't simply mutating the value.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to change the type of the value? If not, and if your value can be assigned to, you can use `map[key] = new_value` or equivalently `hana::at_key(map, key) = new_value`, as `hana::at_key` returns a reference.

If you need the type of the value to change, that's more tricky. We won't be able to do anything in-place, because the type of the map after replacing the value will be different from its type before replacing the value. Hence, we have to create a new map or some kind of modified view of that map (but views are not currently supported). Using `erase_key` and `insert` will indeed cause two maps to be created, which is inefficient. Instead, we could provide some kind of `update` function that would achieve the same, but would create only one copy of the map (the result). I believe we could also do better than `erase_key` + `insert` in terms of compilation times by providing our own function. I opened [this issue](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/278) to keep track of your request, since I think it is important to provide something like this; thanks.

Finally, I'd like to comment what Jason said:

> On another note, perhaps hana::map should be a Functor.

`hana::map` could be made a Functor, but I'm not sure that `transform` could touch the keys of the map while still respecting the Functor laws. If that's not the case, you still wouldn't be able to say "replace the value with XXX if the key satisfies some predicate" using e.g. `hana::replace_if`. I tried (but failed so far) to find an example of functions that would break the laws if `hana::transform` basically transformed the sequence of underlying key/value pairs, but my intuition is that it's possible to find such an example. To be continued in issue #278.